# How use png images as tab icon in ionic-4

Tags: icons, png, angular6, ionic4

Its been two days I am searching for a solution to replace ion-tabs icons with png, I have found many answers in stack also but it's not working with **ionic-4**.

I have followed this answer from ransoing in this [link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/issues/589)

its working when using SVG and with black fills only. however I would like customized image with multicolor in png format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution from ransoing on the link i provided was working. it was just my browser cache thats making the issue

Answer (score 1):

you can use ionTabsDidChange event

```
<ion-tabs (ionTabsDidChange)="tabChange($event)">
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
            <!--<ion-icon name="flash"></ion-icon>-->
            <img src="../../assets/icon/tab/course_on@3x.png" *ngIf="selectTab==='tab1'">
            <img src="../../assets/icon/tab/course_off@3x.png" *ngIf="selectTab!=='tab1'">
            <ion-label>Tab1</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
            <!--<ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>-->
            <img src="../../assets/icon/tab/record_on@3x.png" *ngIf="selectTab==='tab2'">
            <img src="../../assets/icon/tab/record_off@3x.png" *ngIf="selectTab!=='tab2'">
            <ion-label>Tab2</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

```
selectTab = 'tab1';
    tabChange(e) {
        this.selectTab = e.tab;
    }
```